# fitting content into a div without it dropping down

Tags: html, css

I have created a demo of my issue, I am trying to force text next to an image but when you shrink the browser window is knocks it down to underneath the image.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamdanbarrett/88anzh58/)

I need a better approach to this.

```
.avatar_ad_bg_desktop{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url('http://blogs.terrapinn.com/total-real-estate/files/2012/04/SAV_CMYK_LogocopyEng.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    float:left;
}

            <div style="background: red; height: auto; overflow:auto;">

                <div style="background: green;">title</div>
                <div style="background: blue;">Web address</div>

                <div style="float:left;">
                <div class="avatar_ad_bg_desktop">
                </div>

                <div style="float: left;  margin: 0 0px 0 10px; vertical-align:top; word-break: break-all;">Savills plc is a global real estate services provider listed on the London Stock Exchange</div>
            </div>


            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `float:left` on the div with the text, set it with `overflow:auto` (or hidden)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/88anzh58/5/)**

Now resize the browser window and see that the text fills up the remaining width

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table` and `table-cell` format to get better result. Update your HTML like below.

```
   <div style="background: red; height: auto; overflow:auto;">

   <div style="background: green;">title</div>
    <div style="background: blue;">Web address</div>

       <div style="display: table;">
          <div class="avatar_ad_bg_desktop">
          </div>

          <div style="display: table-cell;  margin: 0 0px 0 10px; vertical-align:top; word-break: break-all;">Savills plc is a global real estate services provider listed on the London Stock Exchange</div>
          </div>
       </div>                    
   </div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/88anzh58/6/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `display:table / table-line / table-cell` properties of CSS and remove the `float:left` declarations.
You set the container with `display:table;`
then you can have a `display:table-cell;` for each cells that must stay on the same line.

Here is an updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/88anzh58/4/